# Selenium Python Javascript Execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the problem of running this. I get back an error stating that I either am missing a ) after arguments or that I have an illegal character. I understand that it must be thinking that I am trying to insert an argument when I am not. I believe I just need help with the syntax.

```
    browser.execute_script("url = '/Administration/SwitchCompany?' + jQuery.param({CompanyId: $('#companyDropDownList option:contains('DTLTest')').val() })")

browser.execute_script("$('#userInfoPlaceholder').load(url, switchCompanyCallback);" )
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean

`browser.execute_script("$('#userInfoPlaceholder').load(url, switchCompanyCallback);" )`

Change of `#` to `$`

Comment: that was a mistake writing it into the forum. But in my code that is not there. Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have single quotes inside of single quotes in your javascript:

```
$('#companyDropDownList option:contains('DTLTest')')
```

If you switch the quotes around the full Python string to triple quotes, you could use both single and double quotes in your javascript. Otherwise, you'll need to do some escaping.